# GitPython pull/fetch retrieve progress

Tags: python, gitpython

How do I retrieve the file list when pull/fetch? Assume that the upstream is set and pulling the upstream.

```
repo = git.Repo('/repo_location/')
result = repo.git.pull()
```

According to the API reference, it says the return is iterable list. but i'm unable to use it that way.

If I do `print(result)` it'll correctly prints to stdout, but not when I iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I found no gitpython-method to do this, so I executed `git diff-tree`:

```
repo = Repo(repo_dir)
# first get the remote information to get all changed files, than pull the repository
# has to be done in this order, because after pulling the local repository does not differ from the remote
repo.remote().fetch()
repo.remote().pull()
# the "-t"-option also lists all changed directories
diff_tree = repo.git.execute('git diff-tree --name-status -t master origin/master')

for line in diff_tree.splitlines():
    change_status, file_path = line.split('\t')
```